# Ehcache Expiry and Deadlock

Tags: performance, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I am using hibernate 4.2.20 and ehcache 2.6.6.

I have 2 entities and a spring data repository as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Cache(region = "branch", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public abstract class AbstractBranch{
 .....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch extends AbstractBranch {
}

public interface BranchRepository extends BaseRepository<Branch, UUID> {
     @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"), @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value = "branch") })
     Branch findByBranchId(String branchId);
}
```

In my ehcache.xml I have the following for the Branch cache:

```
<cache name="branch" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="1800" statistics="true" transactionalMode="xa">
```

Now I am trying to run performance tests and everything works great till this cache expires:

Once it expires, and more than one thread calls the finder:

```
branchRepository.findByBranchId(...).
```

I start to get TimeOut/Deadlock exceptions. See the stracktrace be

```
TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[WebContainer : 96,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:197)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:845)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:975)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1293)
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:742)
net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.containsKeyInMemory(FrontEndCacheTier.java:483)
net.sf.ehcache.transaction.AbstractTransactionStore.containsKeyInMemory(AbstractTransactionStore.java:187)
net.sf.ehcache.transaction.AbstractTransactionStore.containsKeyInMemory(AbstractTransactionStore.java:187)
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithStats(Cache.java:1941)
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1584)
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.get(EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.java:74)
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheQueryResultsRegion.get(EhcacheQueryResultsRegion.java:39)
org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.getCachedResults(StandardQueryCache.java:201)
org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.get(StandardQueryCache.java:140)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultFromQueryCache(Loader.java:2477)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2385)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2358)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1230)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:287)
org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:258)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:413)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:391)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findByBranchId(Unknown Source)
```

I have post a thread dump at https://gist.github.com/seamusmac/84843bce06bd0e4fd2f0
which shows the 5 blocked threads.

**Does anyone please, have any idea how to prevent this from happening?**

Comment: I tired using the BlockingCache but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Per EhCache documentation, it seems like these may be "normal" timeout exceptions due to the XA transactional mode you specified in your ehcache.xml...

Such XA mode will use write lock during updates, deletes, or adds... And with concurrent access, these locks cause some threads to block and appear to deadlock. Eventually the deadlocked threads time out (and throw an exception) to avoid being stuck in a deadlock condition.

Check this page https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions.html#transaction-managers where this is clearly mentioned in the FAQ section under the question "Why do some threads regularly time out and throw an exception?"

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reproduced by setting a breakpoint in LocalTransactionStore:put. If a cache has expired fire the first request and the execution will stop in put. Then fire the second request, which will reach remove and wait for the original lock. Restart the first thread and you will have the deadlock.

Here is the reason why I think it locks:

Thread 1: (stack locked) 
    `ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireShared(int) line: 955
    ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).acquireShared(int) line: 1282
    ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock() line: 731
    MemoryOnlyStore(FrontEndCacheTier).isPinned(Object) line: 111
    LocalTransactionStore.put(Element) line: 226
    JtaLocalTransactionStore.put(Element) line: 275`

`private void doAcquireShared(int arg) ->    int r = tryAcquireShared(arg); ->   else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread())`

Thread 2:
(stack setting the exclusive owner thread) 
    `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.setExclusiveOwnerThread(AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.java:56)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquire(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:411)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1245)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.tryLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:1115)
    net.sf.ehcache.concurrent.ReadWriteLockSync.tryLock(ReadWriteLockSync.java:57)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Cache.java:2103)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithStats(Cache.java:1963)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1584)
    org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.TransactionalEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(TransactionalEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:122)
    org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:195)`

(stack locked)
`Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]
    LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: 226
    ReentrantLock$NonfairSync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireNanos(int, long) line: 929
    ReentrantLock$NonfairSync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).tryAcquireNanos(int, long) line: 1245
    ReentrantLock.tryLock(long, TimeUnit) line: 445
    ReadCommittedSoftLockImpl.tryLock(long) line: 85
    LocalTransactionStore.remove(Object) line: 467
    JtaLocalTransactionStore.remove(Object) line: 371
    Cache.removeInternal(Object, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean) line: 2334 
    Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Object, boolean) line: 2117

    Cache.searchInStoreWithStats(Object) line: 1963 
    Cache.get(Object) line: 1584

    TransactionalEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(Object, Object, long, Object, boolean) line: 122`

The second thread setExclusiveOwnerThread as part of: tryAcquireNanos -> tryAcquire(arg) And then parks as part of: tryAcquireNanos -> doAcquireNanos(arg, nanosTimeout) So, it doesn't register a read or write lock, but it leaves the lock with the exclusive owner set.

From this point any call to ReadLock.lock in the first thread will park, because tryAcquireShared fails, since current == getExclusiveOwnerThread() is false, resulting in the deadlock.

Now the question is: Why ReadLock.lock() parks leaving the exclusive owner thread set?

**Update**: Expanding the stacks I've realized that the events happen in different parts of the net.sf.ehcache.Cache and use different classes:

Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Cache.java:2103) -> ReadWriteLockSync.tryLock(ReadWriteLockSync.java:57)

Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Object, boolean) line: 2117 -> (...) ->  ReentrantLock.tryLock(long, TimeUnit)

The first one sets the exclusive owner thread and returns true in the tryAcquire.

ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquire
`protected final boolean tryAcquire(int acquires) {
            /*
             * Walkthrough:
             * 1. If read count nonzero or write count nonzero
             *    and owner is a different thread, fail.
             * 2. If count would saturate, fail. (This can only
             *    happen if count is already nonzero.)
             * 3. Otherwise, this thread is eligible for lock if
             *    it is either a reentrant acquire or
             *    queue policy allows it. If so, update state
             *    and set owner.
             */
            Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
            int c = getState();
            int w = exclusiveCount(c);
            if (c != 0) {
                // (Note: if c != 0 and w == 0 then shared count != 0)
                if (w == 0 || current != getExclusiveOwnerThread())
                    return false;
                if (w + exclusiveCount(acquires) > MAX_COUNT)
                    throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
                // Reentrant acquire
                setState(c + acquires);
                return true;
            }
            if (writerShouldBlock() ||
                !compareAndSetState(c, c + acquires))
                return false;
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        }`

The second one gets false, which leads to doAcquireNanos excecution and park.
    `ReentrantLock$Sync.tryAcquire
     return nonfairTryAcquire(acquires);
    final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
            final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
            int c = getState();
            if (c == 0) {
                if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
                    setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
                int nextc = c + acquires;
                if (nextc < 0) // overflow
                    throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
                setState(nextc);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }`